# A word or succinct description for a compromised media/news outlet

Tags: word-choice, translation

One which is influenced and steered by pressures from a government which itself is corrupt. Doesn't sound too unfamiliar today, does it? 
Anyway, it is to help me translate a German word "die Systempresse".

Comment: In German, possibly "Fuchs."

Comment: Thanks, but I'm after an English word.

Comment: It's a joke.  "Fuchs" means Fox.

Comment: +1 @deadrat - good one, yes, 'fu__s' is the epitome of "a compromised media/news outlet"

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to express this in English, although with different nuances of meaning.  Here are some suggestions:

- biased
- not having a neutral point of view
- partisan (or even "partisan hack")
- state-controlled media
- propaganda

Answer (score 1):

A government-influenced media outlet is often described as a ***mouthpiece*** of that government.

For example, the channel *Russia Today* is often accused of being a mouthpiece for the Russian parliament, the Kremlin.

As in [this *Washington Post*](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/worldviews/wp/2013/06/13/in-case-you-werent-clear-on-russia-todays-relationship-to-moscow-putin-clears-it-up/) article:

> *".... expected it to serve as a **Kremlin mouthpiece**"*

---

**EDIT:** In researching the above I was reminded of another term which fits your requirements well: ***organ***.

I think this word works well because it does also carry a hint of meaning that the government itself is corrupt, as well as the media organisation.

It is used to good effect in the title of [this *Business Insider*](http://www.businessinsider.com/bizarre-russian-headlines-over-ukraine-2014-8?IR=T) article:

> *Here's How The Kremlin's English-Language Propaganda **Organs** Are Spinning Russia's Incursion Into Ukraine*

Answer (score 0):

Gaged press

Not neutral press

Influenced press

Propadanda rag of a corrupt government

Gleichgeschaltete Presse - Forced into line press - synchronized press

Regierungs Sprechorgan - Governmental organ of speach

Government propaganda machinerie

Mrs Merkel's (Obama's etc) handpuppet

Politieker Federn in den Arsch und Journalisten Honig um den Mund schmiere Puppe - Seibert  (that one is rather difficult to translate)

Marionetten Presse - Puppet Press

Corrupt government propaganda organ - seems like the most correct translation tome

Comment: Puppet press seems best for my purposes, thank you for these ideas!

Answer (score -1):

"Propaganda Mill" could be used to describe various media outlets - although, it is most precisely used to refer to the government's own deceptive releases.